# How to reload the fragment page when I was in an activity and used finish() method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say I got a fragment page called "A" and "B" and an activity called "C".
When I click the add button in Fragment B, it will takes the user to activity C. When the user input all the information in activity B and press submit, it will take the user back to fragment B and reload it.

My situation is I use the finish() function on "C" while I press the submit but when it go back to the fragment B it doesn't refresh.

My code:

```
     private View.OnClickListener mSubmitButtonOnClick = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(getArray() != null) {
            insertRecord(getArray());
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(AddClaimFormPage.this, "Please select at least one item to claim.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Please help, how can I reload the fragment B when I used finish()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `onResume()` on fragment B:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    // Load data and do stuff
}
```

Refer [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you have to manage stake of fragment and when you back from another activity to previous activity than load fregment which is the top on stack.